# how to build iOS project in windows system using xcodebuild command line tool

Tags: ios, windows, xcodebuild

I want to build my project in windows system using xcodebuild command line tool

xcodebuild build-for-testing test-without-building -project /xxx/xxxx/xx/xxxx.xcodeproj -scheme xxxx -destination id=UDIDOfDevice

but it gives error :
'xcodebuild>' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Same command work in macOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xcodebuild` is packaged with Xcode, which is a macOS-only app. Thus, `xcodebuild` is also macOS-only. You cannot build an iOS app on Windows with `xcodebuild`